# Why Hibernate session is not reflecting changes done outside application

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

I am developing a `Java` Application which rapidly checks for updates in client database table and if any update is found then transfer it to the server database using `Hibernate` and `MySQL`.

1. It works well when we changes database using hibernate session **BUT** whenever I change the database table value using `MySQL Workbench` then it will return the records which are as before.

How can I get updated with hibernate session on outside changes in table.

```
public List<com.ctpl.models.client.MasterTable> getAllClientMasterTableWithServerFlag() {
    try {
        clientSession = ClientHibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
        clientSession.flush();

        Criteria criteria = clientSession.createCriteria(com.ctpl.models.client.MasterTable.class);
        criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("serverFlag", 0));

        List<com.ctpl.models.client.MasterTable> clientMasterTables = criteria.list();
        clientSession.close();
        return clientMasterTables;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
}
```

What am i missing here ?

Comment: You probably forgot to commit the transaction in MySQL workbench. Or you're not modifying the table/database you think you're modifying.

Comment: Dear @JBNizet I am damn sure about database/table and in MySQL Workbench it's auto commit on BTW I am also committing it manually.

Comment: Then you probably configured a second-level cache, and are getting stale values from this cache.

Comment: Boss @JBNizet there is no second-level cache but I think it's because of first-level cache but I had  read that we can't change `first-level` cache, any other solution please...

Comment: The first cache is associated to the Session instance, and your method creates a new session, so...

Comment: So no solution for me ?       :(

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/75585/discussion-between-gops-and-jb-nizet).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We just need to add connection pooling in hibernate like following...

1. [C3P0 (Easy to implement)](https://sourceforge.net/projects/c3p0/)
2. [BonCP](http://www.jolbox.com/)
3. [Tomcat JDBC Connection Pool](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/jdbc-pool.html)
4. [DBPool](http://www.snaq.net/java/DBPool/)
5. [HikariCP](https://github.com/brettwooldridge/HikariCP)
6. [Proxool](http://proxool.sourceforge.net/)

Found best way to implement it easily using [this example](https://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/how-to-configure-the-c3p0-connection-pool-in-hibernate/)

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at Session.clear() or evict method

Refer to this article:

http://howtodoinjava.com/2013/07/01/understanding-hibernate-first-level-cache-with-example/

Hope that helps

Comment: Thanks for your reply @Godwin but your IDEA for `session.clear()`is not works in this case.BTW it is forces the hibernate.cfg.xml file to reconfigure at every request so I think it's not good IDEA although it's not works here.